# How can I add an Azure VM on Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

How can I add an Azure VM on Azure Active Directory? (not in Azure Active Directory Domain Service) Thanks.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour).

Comment: You can't do this as Azure Active Directory does not support domain joining machines (servers/clients) like traditional Active Directory.  If you are looking for AD like machine management, policy, etc. you can:  setup AD on a VM in Azure and then have this machine join that domain or use AADDS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by adding an Azure VM on AAD. If you mean that you want to have users in a Windows Active Directory on a VM that are synced with your Azure Active Directory, you can do this quite easily. At minimum you will need a Domain Controller VM containing your on-premises directory and a SYNC VM that has AD Connect installed and links your on-prem with your AAD.

Here's how you would go about deploying a VM in the Azure Portal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-portal